# NodeJS: will this code run multi-core or not?

Tags: node.js

I'm using this node script as a "runner" for my project (need to start/stop three scripts at the same time). Now I wonder if the child_process's spawn from inside a node process will or won't use multi cores that my server would have (I'm 90% confident on a YES, but better safe than sorry).

```
    var CP = require("child_process")
      , children = [ 'server1', 'server2', 'server3' ]
      , child

    children.forEach(function(name) {

      child = CP.spawn("node", [name] )

      child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        process.stdout.write(data.toString());
      })

      child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        process.stdout.write(data.toString());
      })
    }
  });
```

OS is Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup. `spawn()` creates completely new processes on the OS-level.

And you could even simplify it a bit by using `pipe()`:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn
  , children = [ 'server1', 'server2', 'server3' ]
  , child

children.forEach(function(name) {
  child = spawn("node", [name] )

  child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
  child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

  // Catch errors (dies quite hard on first child with non-zero exit code...)
  child.on('exit', function (code) {
    if(code !== 0) {
      process.exit(code);
    }
  });
});
```

(Also added listener on `exit`, so it'll at least propagate errors in some way. If it's something you want to do, you may want to keep track of them until the last process has finished, and then call `process.exit()` with the largest or smallest code...)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, Morten! :) [I have the exit handler as well, removed just to save space in the Q]

Answer (score 0):

This will absolutely utilize multiple cores. Node won't, and never should, bind a child process to a specific CPU or CPU core.